# How to fix 'parameter' undefined in Octave

Tags: octave

I'm trying to write a script that will plot a ratio that is calculated between two functions. After multiple attempts at rewriting the functions, I still get the same error that X is undefined. What is being declared inproperly?

Function Code (surface_area.m):

```
function surface_area(x)
  surface_area = 6 .* (x .^ 2);
end
function volume(x)
  volume = x.^3;
end
```

Main Script (main.m):

```
x = linspace(0.1,20);
surface_area;

sa = surface_area(x);
volume = volume(x);
r = sa ./ volume;

plot(x, r)
```

Error Message (running from the main.m script):

```
error: 'x' undefined near line 2 column 24
error: called from
    surface_area at line 2 column 16
    main at line 2 column 1
```

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

When you write `surface_area`, the `surface_area` function is called with 0 parameters. Within the function, `x` is undefined.

Additionally, `volume` is not visible nor accessible from outside the `surface_area.m` file. You can either put it into its own file (called `volume.m`), or you can put it into your script file. But you need to make sure your script file does not start with the definition of a function, because that turns it into a function file. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54013409/7328782) for more info.