# defining variable in an octave function

Tags: syntax, octave

Writing a simple octave code to find factorial and check Sterling's approximation,

> $ vi test.oct

```
function y=f(x)
y = 1;
for i=1:x
y = y*i;  
endfor
endfunction

for i=1:170
x(i)=log(f(i));
y(i)=i*log(i)-i;
z(i)=100.*(x(i)-y(i))/(x(i));
endfor
plot(z)
```

> $ source test.oct

I get the error

```
syntax error near unexpected token `y'  
bash: test.oct: line 4: `y = y*i;'
```

How do I resolve the syntax error in defining variable `y`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run octave script file containing a function definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54013267/run-octave-script-file-containing-a-function-definition)

Comment: You need to fix as described the answer linked above. But you also need to run your script in Octave, you are running it in Bash, as if if were Bash code. Type `octave test.oct`. Alternatively, add a shebang line at the top of the script file (`!# /path/to/octave`) and set the file’s execute flag (`chmod a+x`) and then run it with `./test.oct`.