# How does one correctly use octave function files?

Tags: octave

While familiarising myself with GNU Octave, I've run across a problem which I was not the first to encounter and which is described here:

[Run octave script file containing a function definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54013267/run-octave-script-file-containing-a-function-definition)

Since it seems the right thing to do to put a *function* in a *function file*, I wonder whether I and the author of that question are not using function files correctly. How is one intended to use them? What is their purpose? Or am I right in writing script files instead?

Comment: You're effectively asking about the difference between Functions (or 'function files' to be exact) and Scripts. And also possibly the difference between functions defined as proper function files vs command-line/on-the-spot defined functions (e.g. as part of a script). Confusing, I know. Here are the relevant pages in the manual: [Function files](https://octave.org/doc/v6.4.0/Function-Files.html) / [Scripts (and function definitions inside a script)](https://octave.org/doc/v6.4.0/Script-Files.html). Also worth reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55812060/4183191

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Thanks a lot! I tried to run the .m file, but it's no good. I just set the working directory to the folder where the file was in, and I did not load the file, but trusted Octave to scan the folder automatically, and it worked. Perhaps you should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The filename of a function file should be the same as the function it exports, i.e., the first function in the file.

In the question you refer to, he would have got away simply by naming the file `rectfibo.m`; that would've been a function file. However, the discussion there is about how to export a function from a script file, which is a different animal than a function file.

Comment: Thanks, but the point is that I want to pass some arguments to it. Later on, I even want to generate a function plot!

Comment: That's one more reason why you should make it a function, not a script! As I said, only the first function in the file is the interface to to the file, it may contain any number of other functions. The interface makes it more versatile and shareable. Also, a function doesn't have to return a value and may have side-effects like plots. I've often seen people starting to prototype an idea in a script then transforming it to a function when it became more mature. Not that scripts don't have their utility in the ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

It transpired in the comments that I made the mistake of trying to load the function file, whereas I should have just put it in the current working directory (which can be chosen in the settings), where Octave automatically reads it.

After restarting Octave, having made the above adjustments, it worked perfectly well.

Comment: Alternatively, you can simply add that folder to your 'path'. Have a look [here](https://octave.org/doc/v6.4.0/Manipulating-the-Load-Path.html) for details.